# List of data linked to a certain value in another column

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=15342c401392e5ada9a4d5b93bf6d65d)**

```
CREATE TABLE operations (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    orderID VARCHAR(255),
    itemID VARCHAR(255),
    event_date DATE,
    order_volume INT,
    shipped_volume INT
);

INSERT INTO operations
(itemID, orderID, event_date, order_volume, shipped_volume
)
VALUES 
("Item_01", "Order_01", "2020-01-01", "200", "0"),
("Item_01", "Order_01", "2020-01-18", "0", "50"),
("Item_01", "Order_02", "2020-02-15", "400", "0"),
("Item_01", "Order_02", "2020-02-23", "0", "120"),
("Item_01", "Order_03", "2020-02-21", "300", "0"),
("Item_01", "Order_03", "2020-02-21", "0", "180"),

("Item_02", "Order_01", "2020-02-02", "500", "0"),
("Item_02", "Order_01", "2020-02-10", "0", "175"),
("Item_02", "Order_02", "2020-02-03", "900", "0"),
("Item_02", "Order_02", "2020-03-18", "0", "620"),

("Item_03", "Order_01", "2020-08-12", "700", "0"),
("Item_03", "Order_01", "2020-08-25", "0", "280");
```

**Expected Result:**

```
itemID       orderID       order_volume     shipped_volume          position
Item_03     Order_01           700             280                     1
Item_02     Order_02           900             620                     1
Item_02     Order_01           500             175                     2
Item_01     Order_03           300             180                     1
Item_01     Order_02           400             120                     2
Item_01     Order_01           200              50                     3
```

---

In the above table I have different `items`, their correpsonding `orders` and the `event_date` on which the `order_volume` was ordered and the `shippped_volume` was shipped.

Now, I want to get a **descending** list of all **orders** **linked** to a **certain item**.

For example, `Item_01` is linked to `Order_01`, `Order_02`, `Order_03`. 
Therefore, the `orderIDs` with `Item_01` should be listed from `Order_01` to `Order_03`. 
Additionally, the **position** of each `orderID` within a certain `item` should be displayed as number in column `position`.

---

So far, I was trying to go with the below query but it does not give me the expected result:

```
SELECT
itemID,
orderID,
sum(order_volume),
sum(shipped_volume),
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY orderID ORDER BY event_date DESC) as position
FROM operations
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

What do I need to change to achieve the result displayed above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT
itemID,
orderID,
sum(order_volume),
sum(shipped_volume),
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY orderID ORDER BY itemID DESC) as position
FROM operations
GROUP BY 1,2
order by itemID desc, orderID desc;
```

[**DBFiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=2911a450560827936be23b4854c40fc6)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well:

```
SELECT
itemID,
orderID,
sum(order_volume),
sum(shipped_volume) as ShippedVolume,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY orderID ORDER BY ShippedVolume DESC) as position
FROM operations
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY itemID Desc, ShippedVolume Desc;
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=3f3fa9d28712ac4913a7b0b98ea8e7f7)